# Django Site Admin Objects Not Named Properly

Tags: python, django, web

I'm pretty new to the Django framework. I recently created a few models in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Demographic tags
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    hash_code = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# Legislation (ex. bills, resolutions)
class Legislation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sponsor = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    summary = models.TextField()    # small blurb on top of bill details page
    demographic_tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    raw_html = models.TextField()  # HTML code that includes everything else

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# Concepts (ex. social security, welfare, other general terms)
class Concept(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.TextField()
    demographic_tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    raw_html = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I then made an admin.py that would register my Models as tables in the Django site admin panel:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from civicate.dev.models import Tag, Legislation, Concept

admin.site.register(Tag)
admin.site.register(Legislation)
admin.site.register(Concept)
```

It worked up to this point. When I opened up the Django site admin, the tables for "Legislation," "Tag," as well as "Concept," all showed up successfully. However, when I proceeded to add several objects under the "Tag" table, I saw that they all showed up in the admin panel as "Tag object," not as unique name of the Tag objects themselves.

Any ideas as to how I may fix this issue? I have posted a screenshot of the admin panel from my current point of view.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYTky.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ModelAdmin` to customize your on admin. It's showing up like it because there's nothing to show for `Tag`'s fields.

Try like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display). Create a class for `ModelAdmin` and let your `list_display` to be something like `('id', 'name', )`.

Or maybe

```
def __unicode__(self):
    u"%s" % self.name
```

might work. Specifying it as unicode.

Comment: Never mind - I just forgot to reload apache. Thanks!